# Replacing every element in a matrix

Tags: bash

I have a table of numbers like this --

```
13030 11537 40387 38
31500 174 40387 38
8928 7132 40387 40387 40387 40387 38
1299 174 40387 38
```

All the rows dont have the same number of columns.

I want to make another table of the same size, by replacing the each number with `cmd $number` where cmd is a generic bash command (may be piped). And I want to do the whole thing in bash.

Can this be done?

Comment: When you say do the whole thing in bash, do you mean without any utilities ?

Comment: `I want to make another table of the same size` column in same size? and if it is so, the requirement is not described in detail either. how about one number per line? your would have "same size".

Comment: this question is not clear to me.

Comment: Maybe the expected result will help because it's very unclear to me and wy tag  utilies if only bash is allowed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using xargs. Replace `echo %s + 1 | bc` with your command. My example adds one to each number.

```
xargs -L 1 -i bash -c "printf 'echo -n \"\$(echo %s + 1 | bc) \";' {} ; echo 'echo;'"
```

Answer (score 2):

The next program will do it:

```
while read line
do
  for num in $line
  do
    result=$( cmd $num )
    echo -n "$result "
  done
  echo
done
```